# JS- Countdown Timer Alerts

Tags: javascript

Need some help with my code, I can't get my alerts to work with my countdown timer. They should be alerting at 4,3,2 minutes left on the timer. I currently can't get the alerts to fire at all, sometimes they would fire but each second after 4, the alert for "4" would fire. I need it to just go once... Any help would be appreciated

Heres my script

```
var running=false
var endTime=null
var timerID=null

function startTimer(){
    running=true
    now=new Date()
    now=now.getTime()

        endTime=now+(1000*60*5)
        showCountDown()
}

function showCountDown(){
    var now=new Date()
    now=now.getTime()

    if (endTime-now<=239990 && endTime-now>240010){alert("4")};
    if (endTime-now<=179990 && endTime-now>180010){alert("3")};
    if (endTime-now<=119990 && endTime-now>120010){alert("2")};


    if (endTime-now<=0){
        stopTimer()
        alert("Time is up. Put down pencils")
    } else {
        var delta=new Date(endTime-now)
        var theMin=delta.getMinutes()
        var theSec=delta.getSeconds()
        var theTime=theMin
        theTime+=((theSec<10)?":0" : ":")+theSec
        document.forms[0].timerDisplay.value=theTime
        if (running){
            timeID=setTimeout("showCountDown()",1000)
        }
    }
}

function stopTimer(){
    clearTimeout(timeID)
    running=false
    document.forms[0].timerDisplay.value="0.00"
}
```

Update, Sorry meant minutes instead of seconds

Update 2: Change the ifs, now they fire but keep firing after the 4 second mark

```
    if (endTime-now<=240010 && endTime-now<=239990){alert("4")};
    if (endTime-now<=180010 && endTime-now<=179990){alert("3")};
    if (endTime-now<=120010 && endTime-now<=119990){alert("2")};
```

Comment: Something to remember is that `alert` is blocking - meaning the entire script execution stops while the browser waits for the user to hit OK.  Alerts that are fired in quick succession will end up stacking up.

Comment: Will `endTime-now` ever be less than 239990 **and** greater than 240010? I think not.

Comment: do alert(endTime-now); and see the value, then you can know why you are not getting alerts

Comment: hint: if x is supposed to be in between a and b, what do you write? `x < a && x < b` or `x > a && x > b` or `x > a && x < b`?

Comment: @SpiderPig Removing the equals didn't change the problem of the alerts firing after the 4 min mark

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling clearTimeout? setTimeout invokes its callback only once. There is no need to clear it. Also you could just have a variable that stores the minutes until the end of the countdown and decrement that by one in each iteration.

The simplest solution might look like this

```
function startTimer(minutesToEnd) {
  if(minutesToEnd > 0) {
    if(minutesToEnd <= 4) {
      console.log(minutesToEnd);
    }
    setTimeout(startTimer, 60000, minutesToEnd - 1);
  } else {
    console.log("Time is up. Put down pencils")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually spent some time working on this. I have no idea if this is what you wanted, but I created a timer library. I have a working demo for you. I had fun making this. Let me know what you think:

**JS:**

```
(function () {
    var t = function (o) {
        if (!(this instanceof t)) {
            return new t(o);
        }
        this.target = o.target || null;

        this.message = o.message;
        this.endMessage = o.endMessage;

        //setInterval id
        this.si = -1;

        //Initial start and end
        this.startTime = null;
        this.endTime = null;
        this.interTime = null;
        this.duration = o.duration || 1000 * 60 * 5;

        //looping speed miliseconds it is best to put the loop at a faster speed so it doesn't miss out on something
        this.loop = o.loop || 300;

        //showing results miliseconds
        this.show = o.show || 1000;
    };
    t.fn = t.prototype = {
        init: function () {}
    };
    //exporting
    window.t = t;

})();

//Timer Functions --- 
t.fn.start = function () {
    this.startTime = new Date();
    this.interTime = this.startTime.getTime();
    this.endTime = new Date().setMilliseconds(this.startTime.getMilliseconds() + this.duration);

    //returns undefined... for some reason.
    console.log(this.endTime);

    var $this = this;
    this.writeMessage(this.duration);
    this.si = setInterval(function () {
        var current = new Date(),
            milli = current.getTime();

        if (milli - $this.interTime >= $this.show) {
            var left = $this.endTime- milli;
            if (left <= 0) {
                $this.stop();
            } else {
                $this.interTime = milli;
                $this.writeMessage(left);
            }

        }
    }, this.loop);
    return this;
};

t.fn.writeMessage = function(left){
    this.target.innerHTML = this.message + ' ' + Math.floor(left / 1000);
    return this;
};
t.fn.stop = function () {
    //stopping the timer
    clearInterval(this.si);
    this.target.innerHTML = this.endMessage;
    return this;

};

//Not chainable
t.fn.isRunning = function () {
    return this.timer > -1;
};


var timer = t({
    target: document.getElementById('results'),
    loop: 50,
    duration: 10000,
    show: 1000, //default is at 1000 miliseconds
    message: 'Time left: ', //If this is ommited then only the time left will be shown
    endMessage: 'Time is up. Put down your pencils'
}).start();

document.getElementById('stop').onclick = function(){
    timer.stop();
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="results"></div>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2tozv13/10/)

**Update: I added some stuff**
[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/L2tozv13/12/)

**Update 2: I fixed the bug where 10 would hop straight to 8**

[Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/L2tozv13/13/)